# Does the NHL provide guidelines for collecting stats?

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

Does the NHL or any other league provide guidelines for use by league statisticians?  E.g. for giveaways, takeaways, checks, possession, etc.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is something the NHL only discusses internally at training sessions or other meetings

Comment: I'd love to see this existing somewhere, I'm just not convinced it does.  MLB puts it in their official rulebook, but NHL doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no official manual for statisticians from NHL on the web. There are only some articles explaining some advanced stats like Corsi, Fenwick, PDO... (https://www.nhl.com/lightning/news/hockey-analytics-101-understanding-advanced-stats-and-how-theyre-measured/c-735819).

However there exists an ice-hockey statisticians manual from NCAA where the statistics rules are the same as in the NHL (http://fs.ncaa.org/Docs/stats/Stats_Manuals/IceHockey/2021.pdf).